# Device ID for OneSignal from my Application

Tags: android, cordova, onesignal

I have a web application in which I have added OneSignal and integrated my Cordova app for sending notifications. 
Now,I need to get the `device ID` of the user when he/she logs in.

this can be done in Cordova app like so

```
 window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
    console.log('getIds: ' + JSON.stringify(ids));
    alert("userId = " + ids.userId + ", pushToken = " + ids.pushToken);
    });
```

but I want to get the deviceID on my web application how can I get it?